# Which cell are been calculated when iterative calculation is enable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, circular-reference

I have a workbook that contains 20 sheets, 28K formula, VBA code and multiple UDF. I have extensive circular reference and iterative calculation is enabled. One of the sheets when calculated, does 4 iterations. I expected that the iterative calculation would have been 1 or 2.

The reason I want to optimize the number of iterations, is to improve performance. Currently workbook, essentially an asynchronous mealy state machine, could take well in excess of 10 hours to perform all the calculations.

Having this quantity of formula, looking for the cells that does excessive iterative calculation is impractical.

Is there a way to automatically identify which cells are been calculated when iterative calculation is enabled?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I haven't found a solution, however I use a workaround. Since I have 5 different state, each state is expected to only calculate some cells. Therefore in those specific state I limit the "calculate" to the range that needs update.  It does improve the performance.